# What can I do to find a post I saw earlier today?

Tags: support

Earlier today I saw a post on math.stackexchange regarding why $Ce^x$ is the only solution to $y=y'$. I saw it on my phone and now when I came home I want to study that poster alittle bit more. But I can not find it, what can I do?

Comment: It might be possible to check the browser history on your phone. (Was it a new post or did you just stumble across it?)

Comment: I was using the app, dont think there is a history there? I believe I found it just browsing post on math. @quid

Comment: Maybe is it [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016912)?

Comment: YES! @Watson (caps on purpose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you were looking for was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016912/how-do-we-show-that-the-function-which-is-its-own-derivative-is-exponential).
You can find it on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-11-16%20exponential).
If you want to "keep it in mind", you can mark it as a [favorite question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580).
Then, it will appear on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/229160/olba12?tab=favorites) page.